# Pentaho "Return value id can't be found in the input row"

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a pentaho transformation, which is used to read a text file, to check some conditions( from which you can have errors, such as the number should be a positive number). From this errors I'm creating an excel file and I need for my job the number of the lines in this error file plus to log which lines were with problem.

The problem is that sometimes I have an error " the return values id can't be found in the input row".
This error is not every time. The job is running every night and sometimes it can work without any problems like one month and in one sunny day I just have this error.
I don't think that this is from the file, because if I execute the job again with the same file it is working. I can't understand what is the reason to fail, because it is saying the  value "id", but I don't have such a value/column. Why it is searching a value, which doesn't exists.
Another strange thing is that normally the step, which fails should be executed at all( as far as I know), because no errors were found, so we don't have rows at all to this step.
Maybe the problem is connected with the "Prioritize Stream" step? Here I'm getting all errors( which use exactly the same columns). I tried before the grouping steps to put a sorting, but it didn't help. Now I'm thinking to try with "Blocking step".
The problem is that I don't know why this happen and how to fix it. Any suggestions?
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xrHD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check if all your `aggregates` ins the `Group by` step have a `name`.

However, sometimes the error comes from a previous step: the `group (count...)`  request data from the `Prioritize Stream`, and if that step has an error, the error gets reported mistakenly as coming from the `group` rather than from the `Prioritze`.

Also, you mention a step which should not be executed because there is no data: I do not see any `Filter`  which would prevent rows with missing `id` to flow from the `Prioritize` to the `count`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. It happens randomly in one of my transformations that often ends up with empty stream (no rows). It mostly works, but once in a while it gives this error. It seems to only fail when the stream is empty though.

Comment: Ok someone didn't like my reply, not sure why. I can elaborate on why it is a bug. I have the same code running on 2 different machines. One is a test environment mostly without data (empty streams inside the transformation). The other is a production environment alway with data (runs every 5 minutes, all day all year). The code in test environment fails ca 1 time per day (when running without data). The code in production never fails. It's not a mistake in the code, because the code mostly runs fine with empty data.